# What does *** mean in Python -3?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I was going through an Image Processing Python Script available at http://www.ma.iup.edu/~hedonley/python/ and came across the operator `***`.

What does it mean? I know `*` means multiplication and `**` means exponentiation.

Comment: Since that code was for illustration, it's just a dummy statement to indicate a possible input.

Comment: I assume it's being used as a placeholder so that you put your own values etc in that position. It's not part of Python

Answer (score 5):

It does not mean anything:

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Feb 27 2018, 22:13:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo = ***
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo = ***
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Most likely, in the context of the [article you linked](http://www.ma.iup.edu/~hedonley/python/), it is intended to be a placeholder.